# Get a certain value in a JSON string using a regex

Tags: php, regex, json

How can I extract a specific value using PHP regex and put it in a variable like this:

```
$output = 'testing tag speaker on left';
```

This is how my variable I want to parse looks like:

```
$test ='
\"sticky\": {
    \"type\": \"area\",
    \"positionLeft\": \"23.90625\",
    \"positionTop\": \"19.6875\",
    \"id\": \"false\",
    \"allowToModify\": \"true\"
},
\"area\": {
    \"width\": \"95.625\",
    \"height\": \"170.625\",
    \"caption\": \"testingtagspeakeronleft\"
},
\"spot\": {
    \"bubbleDirection\": \"top\",
    \"title\": \"\",
    \"content\": \"\",
    \"contentRaw\": \"\",
    \"size\": \"0\",
    \"color\": \"white\",
    \"urlSpot\": \"\",
    \"urlSpotTarget\": \"_self\",
    \"urlGoogle\": \"\",
    \"urlYouTube\": \"\",
    \"urlVimeo\": \"\",
    \"urlWikipedia\": \"\",
    \"urlFacebook\": \"\"
}
';
```

Comment: Have you tried json_decode?

Comment: Where do you have this data from?

Comment: @thg435 im not familiar with that but i need this to be done using php

Comment: @hek2mgl it is from wp-stickies

Comment: This looks like a JSON string. You can decode it with `json_decode`. If you don't know what JSON is, try looking it up.

Comment: @hek2mgl hello ur code works fine can you post it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is *almost* json. You need to wrap it in curly braces:

```
// Use double quotes
$test ="\"sticky\":{\"type\":\"area\",\"positionLeft\":\"23.90625\",\"positionTop\":\"19.6875\",\"id\":\"false\",\"allowToModify\":\"true\"},\"area\":{\"width\":\"95.625\",\"height\":\"170.625\",\"caption\":\"testing tag speaker on left\"},\"spot\":{\"bubbleDirection\":\"top\",\"title\":\"\",\"content\":\"\",\"contentRaw\":\"\",\"size\":\"0\",\"color\":\"white\",\"urlSpot\":\"\",\"urlSpotTarget\":\"_self\",\"urlGoogle\":\"\",\"urlYouTube\":\"\",\"urlVimeo\":\"\",\"urlWikipedia\":\"\",\"urlFacebook\":\"\"}";

// Wrap in curly braces
$data = json_decode('{' . $test . '}');

// Obtain desired field    
echo $data->area->caption;
```

However, it would be better to fix this on the point where the data is created.

Answer (score 4):

With all the disclaimers about parsing with regex, if you really have to, this regex gets your tag:

```
\\"caption\\":\\"\K.*?(?=\\"})
```

[See demo](http://regex101.com/r/tO3wC3)

**Explained regex:**

```
  \\                    # '\'
  "caption              # '"caption'
  \\                    # '\'
  ":                    # '":'
  \\                    # '\'
  "                     # '"'
  \K                    # '\K' (resets the starting point of the
                        # reported match)
  .*?                   # any character except \n (0 or more times)
  (?=                   # look ahead to see if there is:
    \\                  # '\'
    "}                  # '"}'
  )                     # end of look-ahead
```

Comment: I'm just curious. What does this have to do with HTML?

Comment: @AmalMurali Haha, nothing. Just typing too fast. Thanks for the heads up. And +1 to your answer, it's terrific that you took care of the non-regex answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

The best course of action would be to **fix the source of the data**. Then you don't have to worry about string manipulation at all. *Always* generate valid JSON. Then you can simply use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to work with it.

This is a JSON string, but with escaped slashes. To get it into a more usable form, you can use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/stripslashes), and then manually convert it into the JSON format by wrapping the string in a pair of curly braces (`{...}`).

Once the string is valid JSON, you can simply use `json_decode()` (with the second parameter set as `true`) to decode it into an associative array:

```
$json = '{'.stripslashes($test).'}';
$arr  = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($arr['area']['caption']);
```

Output:

```
string(27) "testing tag speaker on left"
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/163300)